# load jquery after prototype but cause page processing error

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

I have a javascript lib that might run on different kinds of websites, such as wordpress or magento. The js lib dynamically loads jQuery and call noConflict to assign to another variable namespace in onereadystatechange() of script element. However, if the site also loads Prototype js before my js lib, a conflict between Prototype and jQuery can happen.

Before onereadystatechange callback is called, page might be parsed and a Prototype function might be called. If that Prototype function uses any '$', it causes that function to fail because that dollar sign '$' is still jQuery, not Prototype (before jQuery.noConflict() is called).

My current solution is to check Prototype version and dynamically load it again after jQuery. Something like this:

```
var deps = [];
if(!hasJQueryReqVersion()) {
      deps.push("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js");
      if ( typeof Prototype !== "undefined" ) { // if ptototype exists, load it again to avoid conflict
            deps.push("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/"+Prototype.Version+"/prototype.js");
      }
   }
// iterate deps and create javascript elements
```

Can I ask jQuery not to use '$' at all, so there will be no need to load Prototype again for above reason?

Comment: you can't reload a library arbitrarily on someone else site. WIll rewrite the whole object so if any plugins were previously loaded you will wipe them out causing all sorts of errors to be thrown.

Comment: @charlietfl The script deps will be inserted to header. There is no need to load other libs other than Prototype. Will it be a problem if Prototype reload?

Comment: yes would be a big problem if page author has anything else attached to prototype. Try this with jQuery..  load it once, then load a plugin, then load jQuery again. The try calling plugin... will fail

Comment: OK. How about build a custom jQuery without using dollar sign? Do you have experience to custom build a jquery without $?

Comment: if you are loading it on someone else site you would have to put it in your file, and change it in the file to some other variable name that is unique enough it won't collide

Comment: Okay. I added one question for how to custom jQuery without dollar disn $. http://stackoverflow.com/q/13573570/772481

Comment: you can not load jQuery independently...you need to incluse it in your file , change the name of `jQuery` and keep it insulated from anything else in page

Comment: Thanks. @charlietfl Do you have any example how to achieve this?

Comment: My suggestion is to write it to handle both situations If jquery is available then use it - if PrototypeJS is available use that. This will make your code more compatible with more sites without changing what is loaded on the page.

Comment: The js lib I work on doesn't have dep on Prototype. I understand what you are saying. If page has already an jQuery, use it. Otherwise, use encapsulated jQuery lib.