# Build a custom jQuery without $ dollar sign

Tags: jquery

I have a javascript lib that might run on different kinds of websites, such as wordpress or magento. The js lib dynamically loads jQuery and call noConflict to assign to another variable namespace in onereadystatechange() of script element. However, if the site also loads Prototype js before my js lib, a conflict between Prototype and jQuery can happen.

Before onereadystatechange callback is called, page might be parsed and a Prototype function might be called. If that Prototype function uses any '$', it causes that function to fail because that dollar sign '$' is still jQuery, not Prototype (before jQuery.noConflict() is called).

Can I build a custom jQuery not to use '$' at all, so there will be no need to load Prototype again for above reason?

**EDIT 1:**

Here is the process my js library (mylib.js) will be used on a website and how the jQuery might have conflict with Prototype from that website.

onepage.html from others' website

```
<head>
  <script src="prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="mylib.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

mylib.js

```
1. If jQuery is not defined, create a script element with jQuery src and insert to header.
2. In the script element, attach event onreadystatechange.
  element.attachEvent('onreadystatechange', function () {
  if (elem.readyState == 'loaded' || elem.readyState == 'complete') {
      callback();
    }
  });
3. in callback(), I called noConflict().
   var callback = function() {
     return function() {
        if (window['jQuery'] && hasJQueryReqVersion()) {
           window.myJQ = jQuery.noConflict(true);
        }
     }
   }();
```

Problem is before callback() is called, Prototype might be called and it would accidentally use '$' which has been overridden by jQuery.

Comment: This is a bad approach in my opinion. You'll be loading jQuery regardless of whether or not it is already on the page. Please at least attempt to see if a compatible version of jQuery is already there before you try to load your version. At that point, after you load your jQuery, use `$.noConflict()` as suggested in the existing answers. The order of the libraries won't matter as long as you run `$.noConflict` immediately after including jQuery.

Comment: I did detect if jQuery exists or not. I only load it if it is not there.

Comment: @KevinB the conflict is when I load jQuery but Prototype exists.

Comment: $.noConflict should handle that situation just fine. Can you show us how you are using it that it didn't work? (based on comment on socialrel8's answer)

Comment: I used noConflict at onereadystatechange already. However, before onereadystatechange is called, page processing is still going on and it might call any Prototype function. But before noConflict is called, the Prototype function uses '$' which has been overridden by jQuery.

Comment: the $ shouldn't have been overridden until after the onreadystatechange. Can you show us your implementation?

Comment: If mylib.js is required to run for your prototype to work properly, why isn't that loaded first?

Comment: I am developing mylib.js and people use mylib.js on their sites which might has Prototype dependency. The mylib.js doesn't require any deps on Prototype.

Comment: But prototype does have a dependency on jQuery and mylib.js is what attempts to guarantee that dependency.

Comment: The mylib.js is a widget library that depends on jQuery. Prototype is imported originally. Imagine you are a page owner. You import Prototype for your own page requirements, and import mylib.js to install a widget on your page.

Answer (score 3):

You have control over the order in which the libraries are loaded. Load the jQuery library first (by having that script node in your `<head>` and immediately make the call to `$.noConflict()` before allowing the other scripts to load.

Comment: I am building a javascript lib that can be embedded on other's websites. So I can not control the order. Website owner can include Prototype before my js lib.

Comment: The same way that I can download jQuery plugins from anywhere, but that still requires me to load the jQuery library before the plugins.

Comment: I will check if jQuery is loaded. If not, I will dynamically insert to page. At that time, I can not control jQuery to be loaded first.

Answer (score 2):

Load jQuery first and call `$.noConflict()` immediately.

You can also set jQuery to totally avoid the `$` using something like

```
var JQry = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Comment: I am building a js lib. The jQuery js will be dynamically inserted to page header. I can not control the order. Also, I already called noConflict in onereadystatechange() of that script element of JQuery.